# Can I use a USB for four point impedance measurements

Tags: usb, impedance, bnc

I'm not very familiar with USB's, but I do understand that usually there are four wires, a +5V, a GND, and D+ and D- for data exchange. What my question is, is that currently with a system that I'm using to measure four point impedance measurements, I use straight wires to connect my control board to BNC cables to an LCR meter; however, I wanted to make the system more robust to something more user friendly. I thought that since the USB has basically four electrodes and four wires, I could use it to make the same measurements and just solder the USB cable to the BNC cables.

My question now is a few things:

1.) How does a USB typically power a device. For example, when you plug it into your computer. How does the computer "know" that the red wire should be the supply wire and supply it with 5V.

2.) Is there a difference in the functionality/physical aspects of the power wires in comparison to the data transfer wire. For example, if I were to plug the USB into my control board, would it draw any current from my control board that's powered by batteries? Or would it just simply be four electrodes connected to four wires that I could then solder onto BNC cables?

Any help and explanation would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: 1) There is only one way you can insert a USB connector into your computer USB port.
2) Did you made a typo here? If you wont plug the USB into your board, ofcourse it won't draw any current from it.

Comment: Please don't do this.

Comment: @Golaž yea sorry, it's a typo. If I plug it into my control board*

Answer (score 4):

No, you should not use USB cables or connectors for four-wire resistance measurement.

For one, USB cables and connectors are not manufactured for use with precision instruments. The resistances of the conductors in such an assembly are not tightly controlled, and may fluctuate significantly (with respect to a high-precision resistance measurement) due to even minute changes in temperature or position.

More importantly, using USB connectors for LRC measurement would suggest to a user that they can connect your device or your LRC meter, to a computer, a standard USB device, or a USB power supply (depending on the specific connectors used). Any such configuration would almost certainly cause serious damage to the device and/or your meter.

Don't do this.

Comment: My current set up uses four wires that connects the four electrodes to the LCR meter. How is that different from using a usb since a usb is also essentially four wires.

I'm just trying to understand what makes it different from just any old wire. Are they made of a different material?

Comment: What differentiates each electrode from one another. If I were to cut the GND wire and cut the 5V wire and then solder the 5V wire onto the GND pin and solder the GND wire to the 5V pin, would that make a difference? Or is it just the defined standard that pin 1 is the line that will carry the positive voltage?

Comment: Also, would I be able to use the inner two pins for just a two point measurement instead?

Comment: If you want to accurately measure resistance, it's critical that the resistance of your probe wires is 1) very low and 2) very consistent. The wires in USB cables are neither.

Comment: Thanks so much. One last thing, what makes the USB cables to have those two properties? Is it a special/different material? Or is there something else?

Comment: @Jchen That's typical of any cheaply made cable. Good probe cables are the unusual ones in having stable, low resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use a USB connector for a 4 wire connector. You would have to make sure that there was a ground connection, which may or may not use the outer metal shell. Now, the USB connector is a fairly low voltage, low current connection, so you'd have to make sure that what you are measuring is suitable. If your LCR meter uses more than 5V as an excitation voltage, or drives a test frequency through the connection, it might not work.

However, this is a very bad idea. Duskwuff pointed it out, and I'll add to it. It's a very bad user interface idea to re-purpose a widely used connection for another, incompatible purpose. If I see a USB port on the front of a piece of measurement equipment, I'll expect to be able to use it as a USB port. If I plug a USB drive in it, and your LCR meter drives a 40V signal into the ground and Data lines, I'll end up with a broken USB drive, throw your piece of equipment away, and consider you a horrible design engineer.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much Dave. I was wondering if theoretically it could be used. :)

Comment: Theoretically, you can. And in theory, there's no difference between practice and theory. 

In the reality that we live in, it depends on the exact signals you're trying to carry. For precise measurements, the exact material and mechanical properties of the connector matter, as the mechanical interconnects of the two contacts matter, because of the surface physics involved. USB connectors aren't designed for analog signals, so using them for analog signals may well cause electrical issues.